# padding causes footer to move lower than it is supposed to, causes scroll

Tags: html, css

I've been stuck on getting my footer to be positioned right - specifically, am able to stick it to the bottom but there is still extra space underneath it, causing it to scroll to see the footer. I am fairly sure it is because I use padding in my body section in order to give space at the top of the webpage, but when I set the padding to 0 in the html, body {} section in the css, the space at the top disappears. Is there any way I can keep the space at the top while not creating extra space below the footer? Thanks so much!

JSFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/29e2t/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
        <title>title</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="site_title1">
                Title 1
            </div>
        <div id="site_title2">
                Title 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        </p> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
        </br>
        <p> text text text text text text text text text </p>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <footer>
            <p>I hate footers so much... &copy;</p>
            <br>
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
 }
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
 }
 blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}


/* main font style, background color, and body margins */


body{
font-family: "Calibri", "Candara", "Segoe", "Segoe UI", "Optima", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
color:black;
text-align: left;
background-color: rgb(255,255,224);
padding: 50px 40px 0px 100px


}


/* main header style */

div#site_title1 
{
font-size: 28px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

div#site_title2
{
font-size: 20px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

/*menu style*/

div#menu ul a
{
color:black;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
padding-bottom: 10px;

}

div#menu li
{   display: inline;
}

div#menu ul a:hover
{
color:rgb(188,143,143);
}

div#menu
{word-spacing:5px; }


#menu, #menu a {
padding: 20px;
}

/* about and image positioning */

div#about
{
width:500px;
}

div#images
{
float:right;
padding-right: 375px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

/* event headers and text */

div#eventheader
{
font-size: 18px;
color:rgb(188,143,143);
font-weight: bold;
}

div#eventsubheader
{
font-size: 16px;
color:#000;
font-weight: bold;
}

div#eventtext
{
text-align: left;
font-size: 16px;
color:black;
width:400px;
}

/* table positioning/style */

th{
width:250px;
padding-top: 2%;
padding-bottom: 1%;
}

td{
width:250px;
padding:1%;
}

div#tablelist{
text-align: left;
font-size: 14px;
color:#000;
  }

#tablelist, #tablelist a {
 padding-left:20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
padding-left: 25px;
}


/* misc. */


 a {text-decoration: none;
color:#000;
}

a:hover {color:rgb(188,143,143);}


div#line{
width:400px;
}


 /* footer style */


 html,
body {
margin:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
}
#content {
padding-bottom:100px;  
 }
#footer {
width:100%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;

border-top: 2px solid rgb(188,143,143);
font-size: 12px;
margin-top: 55px;
text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: You can -nearly- always add margin-top:-some px; to the footer to bring it up / compensate. Although its always going to be safer in the long run if you address whyats causing the unexpected layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take care of an issue with box-sizing. You can add something like this to fix it. This will make sure that the height you set for the body is calculated `content + padding = 100%`

```
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/29e2t/2/)**

You should replace `body` with the types of element you want to be affected like `body, div`

What happens is that when you have `min-height: 100%` on the wrapper and then padding on body the height become > 100%